# The property "Class" does not exist in the namespace

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2015, autocompletebox

I am quite new to WPF and am having a hard time with an annoying error message. Here are my steps:

1. Create a new WPF application in Visual Studio 2015. This is the default xaml that is generated for `MainWindow` (this works fine):

   ```
   <Window x:Class="Skype_Utility.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
       xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
       xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
       xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Skype_Utility"
       Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="300">

       <Grid>
       </Grid>
   </Window>
   ```
2. Notice the first 2 lines:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="Skype_Utility.MainWindow"
       xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   ```
3. Next, I grabbed some xaml from [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/795010/An-easy-to-use-WPF-Autocomplete-Textbox), because I am trying to add an auto-complete textbox to the project:

   ```
   <Window x:Class="Skype_Utility.MainWindow"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml "
           xmlns:ac="clr-namespace:WpfAutoComplete.Controls;assembly=WpfAutoComplete" 
           Title="Autocomplete Text Box Project"  
           Height="300" Width="300"> 

       <Grid> 

           <StackPanel> 

               <Label Content="This is an Autocomplete Textbox" /> 

               <ac:TextBoxAutoComplete Name="autoTxtBoxEng" 
                   SearchDataProvider="{Binding Path=MySearchProviderEng}"  
                   SelectedListBoxValue="{Binding Path=PhraseNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"
                   WatermarkText="Type in filtering text here..."/>  

           </StackPanel>

       </Grid>

   </Window>
   ```

However, when I place their xaml into my project, I get this error message:

> The property "Class" does not exist in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml " namespace.

**Even though those are the exact same lines present in the default code, and there was no error given then...**

How can Visual studio complain about this line even though it is literally exactly the same as the first couple of lines that were auto-generated? I have no clue how to progress with this and would really appreciate any advice!

My only thoughts on this really are that there must be some line occurring after the warning which is causing this, but in that case it is a very unhelpful error message!

---

I am unable to build or run my project due to the errors present:

> The name "TextBoxAutoComplete" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:WpfAutoComplete.Controls;assembly=WpfAutoComplete".
>
> ---
>
> The property "Class" does not exist in the "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml " namespace.
>
> ---
>
> The property 'Class' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml '.

Comment: Does it run or is this an actual compiler error?

Comment: (Usually the visual designer has some issues that cause errors that are not even there, and the application compiles and runs anyway)

Comment: Build fails and I also can't run it due to the error. There are also some other errors displayed which I will add to my question now

Comment: The other errors might be the issue. They also can lead to ghost errors because the build failed at a previous step.

Comment: @H.B. I added the other errors. I  actually managed to get rid of the first 2 by adding a reference to `WpfAutoComplete`, but it still complains about the `Class` property, which seems ridiculous ...

Comment: Note those lines aren't _exactly the same_, `Skype_Utility.MainWindow` got changed to `Skype_Utility.Window1`. Changing it back might resolve the Class error.

Comment: @Funk Apologies - I have tried that already and meant to post the code containing `MainWindow` - I also hoped that would fix it

Comment: try a clean and rebuild, also close the xaml file before building. xaml neds to run in order to build the front end and it sometimes gets stuck because the last successful build don't contain something that the current unbuilt project requires then intellisense locks out the compiler because it sees an error that isn't really there

Comment: @MikeT Thanks for your comment. I tried cleaning and then rebuilding but with no effect. It looks like it may work (the main error turns into a warning), but as soon as I open the xaml up again, all 3 errors return... Maybe I should just try a different approach

Comment: You may want to reorder your declarations: the class object is probably defined in one of WinFx schemes

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a space char too much in the end of the `xmlns:x`:

`xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml "` <--- Remove the last char after xaml

so it becomes:

`xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"`